# Select random variable in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, random

I need print value of (i.e. CadetBlue) random var from COLOUR_*
I tried"

```
echo $COLOUR_${NUMBER}
echo "$COLOUR_${NUMBER}"
```

and many others and none is working.

I Have bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBER=$[ ( $RANDOM % 9 )  + 1 ]
echo $NUMBER

COLOUR_1=AliceBlue
COLOUR_2=AntiqueWhite
COLOUR_3=AntiqueWhite1
COLOUR_4=AntiqueWhite2
COLOUR_5=AntiqueWhite3
COLOUR_6=AntiqueWhite4
COLOUR_7=BlanchedAlmond
COLOUR_8=BlueViolet
COLOUR_9=CadetBlue

echo $COLOUR_$NUMBER
```

Comment: `$[...]` is a deprecated syntax; use `$((...))` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Or use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBER=$(( $RANDOM % 9 ))
echo $NUMBER

COLOURS=(AliceBlue AntiqueWhite AntiqueWhite1 AntiqueWhite2
    AntiqueWhite3 AntiqueWhite4 BlanchedAlmond BlueViolet CadetBlue)

echo ${COLOURS[$NUMBER]}
```

Comment: +1 although you don't need the line continuation when declaring the array.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of saying

```
echo $COLOUR_$NUMBER
```

say:

```
color=COLOUR_${NUMBER}
echo ${!color}
```

You can read more about *indirect expansion* [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).